# how to override the verbose name of a superclass model field in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

Let's say that I have a model Foo that inherits from SuperFoo:

```
class SuperFoo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of SuperFoo instance', max_length=50)
    ...

class Foo(SuperFoo):
    ... # do something that changes verbose_name of name field of SuperFoo
```

In class Foo, I'd like to override the verbose_name of the name field of SuperFoo. Can I? If not, is the best option setting a label inside the model form definition to get it displayed in a template?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! So we can either (i) set a label inside a form, or (ii) set verbose_name after defining the class via _meta.get_fields method. both are easy to implement, however I think I'll prefer using the _meta.get_fields method so that I can keep all model-relevant things inside the models module.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A simple hack I have used is:

```
class SuperFoo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of SuperFoo instance', max_length=50)
    ...
    class Meta: 
        abstract = True

class Foo(SuperFoo):
    ... # do something that changes verbose_name of name field of SuperFoo
Foo._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name = 'Whatever'
```

Comment: This actually changes the verbose_name of the field for the SuperFoo class. For example, if you have: class Bar(SuperFoo), the verbose_name for the 'name' field is also 'Whatever'... even if you follow the same procedure with Bar._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name = 'Whatever 2'

Comment: If SuperFoo is an abstract base class, the above comment is not true. This method works well as long as the SuperFoo class is abstract, so class Meta: abstract = True

Comment: The problem is sometimes SuperFoo can't be abstract

Answer (score 10):

Bearing in mind the caveat that modifying Foo._meta.fields will affect the superclass too - and therefore is only really useful if the superclass is abstract, I've wrapped the answer @Gerry gave up as a reusable class decorator:

```
def modify_fields(**kwargs):
    def wrap(cls):
        for field, prop_dict in kwargs.items():
            for prop, val in prop_dict.items():
                setattr(cls._meta.get_field(field), prop, val)
        return cls
    return wrap
```

Use it like this:

```
@modify_fields(timestamp={
    'verbose_name': 'Available From',
    'help_text': 'Earliest date you can book this'})
class Purchase(BaseOrderItem):
    pass
```

The example above changes the verbose_name and help_text for the inherited field 'timestamp'. You can pass in as many keyword args as there are fields you want to modify.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm on Django 1.11.4 .

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be setting/changing the label in the form itself. Referring to the `name` field of the `Foo` model (eg. by looking it up in `Foo._meta.fields`) will actually give you a reference to the `name` field of `SuperFoo`, so changing its `verbose_name` will change it in both models.

Also, adding a `name` field to the `Foo` class won't work either, [because](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted)...

> Overriding fields in a parent model
>   leads to difficulties in areas such as
>   initialising new instances (specifying
>   which field is being intialised in
>   `Model.__init__`) and serialization.
>   These are features which normal Python
>   class inheritance doesn't have to deal
>   with in quite the same way, so the
>   difference between Django model
>   inheritance and Python class
>   inheritance isn't merely arbitrary.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at how Django-CMS does this, they override the `db_table` field in the models inheriting from `CMSPlugin`. The basics (which I also use for my own stuff) boil down to:

```
class SuperFooMetaClass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(SuperFooMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class._meta.verbose_name = "...."   # perhaps only if not customized
        return new_class


class SuperFoo(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = SuperFooMetaClass

    ....
```

You can add some checks, e.g. only update for subclasses (not the direct type), or only update if the value is not customized.

Answer (score 1):

I have different child classes deriving from the same base class. And I only care for the form view in the Django Admin interface.

The only solution that worked for me was to customize the Django Admin interface and set the verbose_name (or help_text) there:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['name'].verbose_name = "my verbose name"
        return form

admin.site.register(models.Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: This only worked if I used the assigned the new label to the `label` property, not the `verbose_name` property. Example: `form.base_fields['<field_name>'].label = "<custom label>"`. I'm using Django 3.2.