# Django - Allow duplicate usernames

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm working on a project in django which calls for having separate groups of users in their own `username` namespace.

So for example, I might have multiple "organizations", and `username` should only have to be unique within that organization.

I know I can do this by using another model that contains a username/organization id, but that still leaves this useless (and required) field on the defualt django auth `User` that I would have to populate with something.

I've already written by own auth backend that authenticates a user against LDAP.  However, as I mentioned before, I am still stuck with the problem of how to populate / ignore the `username` field on the default django user.

Is there a way to drop the uniqueness constraint for the `username` for Django auth users?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I think you could use a hack similar to what is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927729/how-to-override-the-verbose-name-of-a-superclass-model-field-in-django).

The following code works, as long as it is in a place that gets executed when Django loads your models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User._meta.get_field('username')._unique = False
```

Note that this won't change the database unique constraint on the `auth_user` table if it has been already been created.   Therefore you need to make this change **before** you run syncdb.  Alternatively, if you don't want to recreate your `auth_user` table, you could make this change and then manually alter the database table to remove the constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work. The `unique` attribute is propagated to the database as a constraint on that field. Once that's done, tweaking Django meta info isn't going to help. If you're never going to actually *use* (i.e. display/modify) the username, then anything to make it unique will suffice. E.g. what DrBloodmoney suggests.

Comment: This *does* work (I tried it), but since it's accessing `_meta`, it's relying on the internal implementation and not the documented interface, so I'm wary to use it.  +1 though, it does work.

Comment: Well, it works on NOT NULL constraints (I've tried that), so I don't see why not. As long as "MyUserModel" is a class which inherits from "auth.User" and the line is put in straight after the model, this seems to work. It's just that it's a slightly ugly hack.

Comment: This actually works just fine without subclassing `auth.User`.   You can just do `User._meta.get_field('username').unique = False`.   It does work, as long as it exists in a file that gets loaded when Django loads your models.   I'm accepting this answer, since it's functional, but I still feel like it's not a very good solution, as it may break with updates to Django (it relies on undocumented internal functionality).

Comment: If this works, I need someone to explain it to me. There are (at least) 2 problems: 1) the field is `_unique`, not `unique`. (At least in 1.1.1 this is true. In 0.97pre it was `unique`.) 2) Regardless of the name, setting the `_unique` field makes no change to the *database enforced constraint* that the field is *unique*, a constraint that was created at syncdb time and which does not disappear by setting this field. I await enlightenment. Truly, I do.

Comment: @TM Oh, that's interesting... I didn't think it would work on the original User model, but that's good to know... Yeah, if you ever find a way to do this sort of thing without resorting to ugly hacks, I'm interested too!

Comment: @Peter Rowell I don't know about 1), but in terms of 2) now that I've started pondering the question and TM has said this works in more contexts than I thought, my guess is that django has to know all the models from the project before executing the CREATE TABLE sql because they need to be executed in the correct order (foreign keys). Therefore, I suppose the meta data is still possible to change even after the model declaration because the sql isn't formed until all the models are declared... Just a guess though.

Comment: @PeterRowell, yes you are correct, it has to be `_unique` not unique.  My mistake.   Sadly, I can't edit that comment anymore.    As for issue #2: you need to make this change *before* you run syncdb to create the auth_user table.   If you do this, the database constraint will not be created.   Alternatively, if you already have run syncdb, you can alter the table manually.   @Monika, it would be good if you could update your answer to use `_unique` and do the change directly on `User`.

Comment: Sometimes I forget I can edit other peoples answers myself...  I updated this answer to make it more accurate/clear, in order to address PeterRowells concerns.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is extend the User model. For the User table, generate a username (e.g. A_123, A_345) that will not be displayed at all in the site.

Then create a new model that extends User.

```
class AppUser(User):
    username = models.CharField...
    organization = models.CharField...
```

You then create a custom authentication backend that use AppUser instead of the User object.

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally been required to find a solution to this, but one way to tackle this (from an SAAS perspective) would be to prefix the username with an organizational identifier (presuming unique organizations).  For example: subdomain.yoursite.com would equate to a user with the username: subdomain_username. You would just have to code some business logic on login to a subdomain to tack that onto the username.

Comment: Yes, this works, and I considered, but the username is already only 30 characters, and adding the prefix quickly reduces the size to something that is unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered with this problem. I was doing a project where I had to use email and mobile no. as login fields but none of them should be unique because their were different types of users and a user can have more than one user entity and also the project required only one auth user table (Hectic right!).

So I extended AbstractBaseUser class where I could change the USERNAME_FIELD attribute. Here's how :-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

# Custom model for User
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(UserTypes, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    # Here's the Catch
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

Yes exactly, surprised? USERNAME_FIELD should be a unique field that's the constraint of this attribute. I couldn't use email or mobile no. as unique field.

Then I created a custom manager to remove the username field (reference = https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser)

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Did you find any side-effects of this? Is USERNAME_FIELD actually used by any of the underlying django or DRF modules? (I didn't search exhaustively for this yet..)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact same problem and I've been reading a lot (about how to solve that problem in 1.5) and I just thought of a much simpler solution. What if you just add a fixed-length prefix with the organization id to store the username?

I.e. Organization id = 115, chosen username = "john" and a fixed length of 6. So in the data base you store as username "000115_john".

When you do the login you just join the two parameters and try to authenticate with what Django provides. I'm not sure if the fixed length is strictly necessary but could avoid undesirable results if a user chooses a username with only numbers.

Comment: If you want answers, post this as a question.