# Django: Override field label or help_text in child Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a few models that all have some common functionality. Each Model is a physically stocked type of item so they share things like `stock` and also share some things like low stock warning events (sends an email).

Rather than duplicate the code, I wrote an abstract Model and inheritited from it.

```
class LowStockModel(models.Model):
    stock = stock = models.IntegerField()
    out_of_stock_behaviour = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[...])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.stock <= 0:
            #...
```

My problem is I need to change the label or add different `help_text` to the `stock` field in the child classes I'm spawning. It's very important because the client (and their staff) need instructions on the units. I've tried munging around in the child `__init__` but I'm not getting anywhere.

**tl;dr** How can you change the label on a field from a child model?

Comment: Don't do this: `super(self.__class__, self)` You can easily get infinite recursion.

Comment: It's not gonna be pretty, but : http://stackoverflow.com/a/928774/16361

Answer (score 5):

When inheritance is made from an abstract class, in Django you may want to use:

`CustomClass._meta.get_field('yourfield').verbose_name = 'Your custom text'`

Your classes should be like:

```
class AncestorClass(models.Model):
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='AncestorStockName')
    # etc ...
```

And now we should customize the child class like this:

```
class ChildClass(AncestorClass):
     stock = models.CharField... # Customize your stock field

ChildClass._meta.get_field('stock').verbose_name = 'CustomVerboseStock'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stock '].label = "any label"
```