# Django, How to change "blank" attribute of field from parent model?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I got two models, for example:

```
Parent(models.Model):
    mytext= models.Chafield(max_lenght=250, blank=True)

Child(Parent):
    mytext_comment=models.Chafield(max_lenght=250)
```

But in child I want `mytext` to be obligatory.
Do it will be sufficient to invoke `mytext.blank=False` in child `__init__` ?
Caution this are not abstract methods because I want to be able to use Manager on Parent (Parent.objects.all() for example)

Comment: I'm begging to see it will be problematic. Worst case I will do it in form validation, or by custom field validators. Will be glad to hear your opinions on best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. From Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted):

> This restriction only applies to attributes which are Field instances.
>   Normal Python attributes can be overridden if you wish. It also only
>   applies to the name of the attribute as Python sees it: if you are
>   manually specifying the database column name, you can have the same
>   column name appearing in both a child and an ancestor model for
>   multi-table inheritance (they are columns in two different database
>   tables).

PS: I tried to like you suggested, but I get error like `unicode object has no attribute blank`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can try this solution:

```
Parent(models.Model):
    mytext= models.Chafield(max_lenght=250, blank=True)

Child(Parent):
    mytext_comment=models.Chafield(max_lenght=250)
Child._meta.get_field('mytext').blank = True
```

Can you please let me know if it works ?

Comment: Going out of work for today, will try it tomorrow and give you feedback.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/a/928774/1016772 in  mtaube's comment's is stated that it changes super class property so it will probably break parent. Is good if parent is abstract but not in my case - I plan to use parent to i.a. make list views that list all children in one place, and abstract methods don't have managers...

Answer (score 0):

As the discussion goes on I think the correct answer is:

You don't do it on model level. I should do this kind of validation on form level not in a model. Best places are: form fields parameters or form clean method