# Modifying verbose names for django model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to do something like this:

```
#core/models.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

BaseModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(self.__name__ + ' name'))
    ...
    ...
    ...

#myapp/models.py

class MyModel(BaseModel):

#myapp2/models.py

class MyModel2(BaseModel):
```

so when the verbose names of `MyModel.name` and `MyModel2.name` is accessed it is `'MyModel name'` and `'MyModel2 name'` respectively.

However this code doesn't work as there is no `self.__name__` in a `BaseModel` class namespace. In fact i have other fields on my `BaseModel` which i also would like to work in a such way that they take the Concrete model name and add it to verbose_name in a manner `(%class_name% + ' %verbose name taken from BaseModel field verbose_name declaration%')`

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6426278/7806)